# Can I use predict on a basic land card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There is this card "[Predict](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPredict%5d)" that reads

> Name a card, then put the top card of target player's library into his or her graveyard. If that card is the named card, you draw two cards. Otherwise, you draw a card.

Reading its text on Gatherer.Wizards.com, the Oracle text reads as

> Choose a card name, then target player puts the top card of their library into their graveyard. If that card has the chosen name, you draw two cards. Otherwise, you draw a card.

My doubt is, can I name a basic land card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Basic land cards are cards, so you can choose their names when instructed to choose a card name.

[Rule 201.3](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Name) governs choosing card names:

> If an effect instructs a player to choose a card name, the player must choose the name of a card in the Oracle card reference. (See rule 108.1.) A player may not choose the name of a token unless it’s also the name of a card.

Basic land cards are in the Oracle reference, so you can choose them.

Answer (score 1):

Note that several cards, such as [Desperate Research](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDesperate%20Research%5d), say "Name a card other than a basic land." The fact that Predict doesn't is a strong indication that they are valid names. Cards in MTG generally mean *exactly* what they say, nothing more and nothing less.